# Как убрать отступ?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Начал изучать Html+Css и начал верстать сайт по макету который сделал в Figma. Никак не могу убрать отступ сверху, буду признателен, если поможете!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu-photo{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mainphoto{
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu-btn{
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20;
  left:20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
 
.menu-btn > span,
.menu-btn > span::before,
.menu-btn > span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
.menu-btn > span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}
.menu-btn > span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}
 
.menubox{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
 
.menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
 
 
#menu-toggle{
  opacity: 0;
}
 
#menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-btn > span{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-btn > span::before{
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}
#menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu-btn > span::after{
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#menu-toggle:checked ~ .menubox{
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Туры по фьордам</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-menu_photo">
        <img id="mainphoto" src="MainPhoto.jpg" alt="Ой, что то пошло не так!" align="center" width="100%" height="720px">
    </div>
    <div class="burger-menu">
    <input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="menu-btn" for="menu-toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="menubox">
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">О нас</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Туры</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы использовали  `<input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" />` и так задали прозрачность `#menu-toggle { opacity: 0;}`. Но элемент на странице занимает место. Для того чтобы убрать к `#menu-toggle`  сделайте `display: none;`

Comment: Спасибо!!!  Помогло)

Comment: @Dima рад был помочь )) успехов